# databricks not seeing data I expect

Tags: sql, databricks

trying to query a table in DB.

```
%sql SELECT 'Status' FROM checkins_csv WHERE 'Status' IS NOT NULL;
```

getting back the following:

[image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong and not seeing data?

Comment: When you write `select 'status'` you are adding that string (ie, "status") to every row. You're not actually selecting a column from the table. Try `select status from checkins_csv where status is not null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes think you are making a pseudo (string) column in your results. You just need to remove the single quotes in your query:

```
%sql 
SELECT status FROM checkins_csv WHERE status IS NOT NULL;
```

To better illustrate, run this too, which creates two additional columns:

```
%sql 
SELECT 'Bacon', 1, status FROM checkins_csv WHERE status IS NOT NULL;
```